# What is the windows phone app image asset that is displayed when in the list of open apps

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, assets, graphical-logo

I'm starting with developing on Windows phone 8.1. I've been working with the different image assets for logos and tiles, but have not been able to identify the one that is displayed when you go to the list of open apps (i.e. pressing and holding the back key). In this view there is a logo of the app in the bottom-left corner that I don't know from where it comes. I'm trying to change the background color of it, but is none of the ones define in the manifest. I've seen apps that have this image with a specific background color (i.e. not transparent) like the one in the screenshot below. So, there must be a way to do it, but I'm not able to find where or how.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

That would be the application icon you set in your `WMAppManifest.xml`. You can find this under your project's `Properties` folder. You can set icon from the UI (App icon) or by editing the XML block itself.

```
<IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Assets\ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
```

This is the same icon that is shown in phone's app list. If image has transparency, phone's selected accent color is shown as "background". If not, well.. then it won't be transparent :).

Comment: The App Manifest also has a designer, which is straight-forward to use.

Comment: Yes, as stated "you can set icon from the UI". Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @mikkoviitala, I'm developing in Windows Phone **8.1**. There is no file `WMAppManifest.xml` in the `Properties` folder. In this folder there is only the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. There is though a file `Package.appxmanifest` in the main project folder that I can edit via the UI and has a number of assets for splashscreen, tiles, logos, etc. However, none of the available assets corresponds to the image indicated in my question. The assets in this file are: `Square 71x71 Logo`, `Square 150x50 Logo`, `Wide 310x150 Logo`, `Square 44x44 Logo`, `Store Logo`, `Badge Logo`, and `Splash Screen`

Comment: You are right, this not for 8.1. All I can think of is to lookup reference and specify all app's visual elements and hope for the best. Or put up a bounty on this question if you can.